# mingw32-make ERROR, error: 'once_flag' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: c++, mingw

```
c:\libapiai-master\libapiai-master\build\examples>mingw32-make install
mingw32-make install
[  5%] Built target indent_stream_library
[ 10%] Built target cJson
[ 12%] Building CXX object apiai/CMakeFiles/apiai.dir/src/AI.cpp.obj
C:\libapiai-master\libapiai-master\apiai\src\AI.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
 #include <apiai/AI.h>
 ^
C:\libapiai-master\libapiai-master\apiai\src\AI.cpp: In static member function 'static ai::Service& ai::AI::sharedService()':
C:\libapiai-master\libapiai-master\apiai\src\AI.cpp:42:12: error: 'once_flag' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
     static std::once_flag once_flag;
            ^
C:\libapiai-master\libapiai-master\apiai\src\AI.cpp:45:5: error: 'call_once' is not a member of 'std'
     std::call_once(once_flag, [](){
     ^
C:\libapiai-master\libapiai-master\apiai\src\AI.cpp:45:20: error: 'once_flag' was not declared in this scope
     std::call_once(once_flag, [](){
                    ^
apiai\CMakeFiles\apiai.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'apiai/CMakeFiles/apiai.dir/src/AI.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[16]: *** [apiai/CMakeFiles/apiai.dir/src/AI.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:179: recipe for target 'apiai/CMakeFiles/apiai.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[15]: *** [apiai/CMakeFiles/apiai.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make[14]: *** [all] Error 2
```

I built api.ai library. I used MinGW to that.
I made Makefile, but I made new error too.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

MinGW (but not MinGW-w64) does not currently support the full pthread interface, including `std::once_flag`.

You should switch to MinGW-w64 (pthread support) or use the Win32 API. Furthermore, MinGW with [mingw-std-threads](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads), you can have partial threading support.

Comment: You can also use mingw-w64 with win32 threads and the meganz thread addon

Answer (score 2):

You did not pass the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: I added `add_compile_options(-std=c++11)` to CMakeLists.txt.
But I didn't work. Help me please.

Comment: Add it to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, you can pass it to cmake via -Dvarname=value.

Comment: I found it already added before...... I have searched that reason for two days. but solution is not existed...

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and check whether the flag gets really added.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mingw version, maybe it doesn't support 'once'. Or maybe 'once' contains in another header. Report issue to github, I'll try to resolve it. https://github.com/api-ai/libapiai

Answer (score 0):

I tried this workraound and it worked for me:

make the modification on detection_based_tracker.cpp

`//#if (defined(__cplusplus) &&  __cplusplus > 199711L) || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1700)
//#define USE_STD_THREADS
//#endif`

Answer (score 0):

MinWg64 install has two type of threads: **win32** and **posix**.
if you install with win32, maybe you can reinstall with "posix".
[image]